# Removing word + wildcard number from string

Tags: php

I have a string that is

```
$str = "testingSUB1";
```

How can I strip out `SUB*` from the string? I assume using `preg_replace` but I'm not good with matching what I want with regex.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way.

```
$str = preg_replace("#SUB[0-9]+#", "", $str);
```

The `#`s are delimiters; they can be any non-alphanumeric/whitespace/backslash character that doesn't appear in the pattern. `[0-9]` means any digit (you can use `\d` too in some languages, but I usually don't bother), and the `+` means one or more of the previous, so if you take the `+` out it will only replace the first digit

Comment: I got in the habit of using # because it rarely comes up in the pattern, whereas / shows up all the time (in URLs or Linux paths, for example). / will work though

Comment: Always use `'` whenever possible in place of `"` also `+ means any number of the previous` is incorrect it means `one or more`

Comment: I fixed the definition of `+`, but as for the quotes, if you're so concerned about performance that you're actually shaving off a few milliseconds using `'` instead of `"`, you're programming in the wrong language

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$word = 'SUB';
$string = 'testingSUB1';

echo preg_replace('~^(.*?)(' . preg_quote($word, '~') . '\d+)(.*?)$~', '$1$2', $string);
```

**EDIT - This is better:**

```
echo preg_replace('~' . preg_quote($word, '~') . '\d+~', '', $string);
```